# Get earliest and latest times from a list of datetimes

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have,

```
timestamp=[]
for x in model_obj:
     timestamp.append(x.start_time)

print timestamp
```

RESULT:

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 19, 40, 1, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 19, 40, 14, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 19, 40, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 21, 53, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 22, 25, 24, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 22, 2
5, 52, tzinfo=<UTC>)]
```

My question is: How to get the earliest and latest times from this list of datetimes in python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the built-in `min()`/`max()` functions:

```
earliest = min(timestamp)
latest = max(timestamp)
```

As side note I suggest you to build the list with the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
timestamp = [x.start_time for x in model_obj]
```

**UPDATE**: The earliest representable `datetime` is [`0001-01-01 00:00:00`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min) so as far as I understand the `0000-00-00` date can't be loaded from database and you get the `None` in the `x.Date_Time_End` field.

The question is: does your task allow you to  ignore this datetime?  If yes then just filter out `None` values from the list:

```
end = [x.Date_Time_End for model2_obj if x.Date_Time_End]
end_time = max(end)
```

Comment: What if I need to get min and max from date list like  timestamp = [ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , 2014-09-01 05:03:56, 2014-09-01 06:25:05 ] ?

Comment: If dates are formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD` then the same `min()`/`max()` functions will work just fine. If dates are int the `YYYY-DD-MM` format then you have to add the `key` argument to these functions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min

Comment: All the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format. Whenever there is a date 0000-00-00 00:00:00 comes the max giving me a null value as a result. Even though there is valid dates in the list. Please help me on this.

Comment: `end = []             
for x in model2_obj:    
end.append(x.Date_Time_End)
 end_time =  max(pdb_end)`           
But it returns an error "TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to NoneType"